# how should i use Emmet abbreviation in July update of VS code for windows 11

Tags: emmet

Emmet abbreviation  for shift + 1 ! not providing boilerplate code for  HTML for  windows 11 for July update (June 2022 (version 1.69)) of vs code .for previous May update (May 2022 (version 1.68))its working fine .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Gustavo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72955877/19530650) has linked to Github issue currently affecting all users.

Open VS Code Settings.
Type 'Emmet' in the searchbox.
Among the settings listed below, ensure `Emmet: Trigger Expansion On Tab` checkbox is ticked.
Create any html file. Press `!` and then `Tab` (Even if no visual indicator comes, as in previous versions of VS Code, it should fill the boilerplate).

(Update: VS Code version 1.69.2 is released & restores the Emmet functionality.)