# I can't use emmet "!" in vs code 1.69.0

Tags: html

I want to use emmet "!" but I can't . I can use other shortcuts but this particular function. Please help me solve it.

Comment: Issue is already on `GitHub` use `html:5` instead.

Answer (score 0):

It's a very known bug in reference to https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/154375.

Switch to `html:5`.